# Query Builder de Adonis ¿Como obtener el id?

Tags: nodejs, adonisjs, adonis-4

¡Hola amigos! Soy relativamente nuevo en programación, hasta hace poco me las había apañado bien con adonis js debido a que solo había utilizado las funciones más escenciales del framework, entre ellas las más escenciales del Query Builder las cuales te regresan los datos de la tabla en automatico, no obstante debido a la naturaleza "especial" de una de mis tablas tuve que investigar un poco más para arreglarmelas en la obtención de datos

```
const conversations  = await Conversation.query()
        .select('user1.username AS Emisor', 
        'user2.username AS Receptor',
        'user1.avatar AS Emisoravatar',
        'user2.avatar AS Receptoravatar'
        )
        .join('users as user1', 'conversations.from_user_id', '=', 'user1.id')
        .join('users as user2', 'conversations.to_user_id', '=', 'user2.id')
        .where(function () {
          this.orWhere('from_user_id', me.id)
          this.orWhere('to_user_id', me.id )
        })
        .with('seenders')
        .fetch()
```

El problema con este método es que no me regresa el id ni otros datos propios de la tabla intenté buscar un poco en Google y me topé con que el framework no es tan conocido y mi ingles es pesimo por lo que tengo horas intentando arreglarlo a como he podido entender no obstante tampoco alcanzo a entender del todo la función de Join (Es la primera vez que la utilizo, intenté buscar en la documentación pero mi ingles es pesimo y no me queda del todo claro) Si alguien pudiese ayudarme estaría muy muy muy agradecido

Comment: En este caso el id de la tabla Conversations que vendria siendo el padre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debería de bastar que en el método `select()` indiques el listado de columnas a recuperar, recuerda que no deja de ser un *vector* entonces pasa los valores que deseas separados por coma así:

```
 .select(
         'conversations.id',
         'conversations.unacolumnaMas',
         'conversations.otracolumnamas',
         'user1.username AS Emisor', 
         'user2.username AS Receptor',
         'user1.avatar AS Emisoravatar',
         'user2.avatar AS Receptoravatar'
        )
```

Como vez del caso anterior indicamos la tabla y columna a recuperar por medio de la sintaxis `tabla.columna`, no te trae nada de la tabla `conversations` por que no esta indicado en el `select()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ya había intentado 'conversations.id' pero al parecer yo lo tenía pensado como una sola tabla individual y lo ponía en singular 'conversation.id' La función de callback en el where la tuve que poner debido a que me mandaba error leí por ahí que se trataba de un bug de adonis pero no estoy seguro